# Box SDK Refresh Token method (python)

Tags: python, sdk, box

I am trying to implement python-sdk to drop a file (that exists in a local folder) into a shared Box folder.

The method I tried is to put Redirect URI into my Box developer configuration page and use Client ID/Secret to get `authorization_URL` and then extract authenticate code extract access token and refresh token.

However, I can only get to the part of getting the `auth_url` and I can only get `auth_code` manually from the redirecting to the page after clicking "granting" the access.

Using that `auth_code` I can get the refresh token but I don't know how to automate that part.

Is there another approach to this?

If so, can you please give me an example how?

I have literally read every search related to this and so far I haven't found a solution to my problem.

```
Redirect_URi = 'https://api.box.com/oauth2/token'

def save_tokens(access_token,refresh_token):
    print("Refreshing tokens...")
    target = open("AdminToken.txt", 'w')
    target.truncate()
    tokens = access_token+'#'+refresh_token
    target.write(tokens)
    target.close()

oauth = OAuth2(
client_id=CLIENT_ID,
client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
store_tokens=save_tokens
)
oauth.access_token
auth_url, csrf_token = oauth.get_authorization_url(Redirect_URi)
# GET "auth_code" from auth_url #
getTokens = requests.get(auth_url)
# trouble starts here
auth_code = 'exctracted from linked webpages manually' # expires in 30 seconds after creation
access_token, refresh_token = oauth.authenticate(auth_code)

oauth2 = OAuth2(
client_id=CLIENT_ID,
client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
store_tokens=save_tokens,
access_token=access_token,
refresh_token=refresh_token
)

client = Client(oauth)
# Testing if it is authorized
me = client.user(user_id= user_id).get()
print ('user_login: ' + me['login'])`
```

I should be able to run this script and the file I extracted from DB should be picked up as xlsx (which I already did) and dropped into Box folder.

I think I am stuck here with this refresh tokens and everyone is directing me to Github official Box sdk page without giving any more information like any example on it.

Comment: hello miih , I have write code to upload and download file from box which is working absolutely fine. But access token is getting expire after every 1 hr. I think you had work on same, can you please suggest me how do I refresh token dynamically if one is expired.I am working with python sdk only.

Comment: have you figured it out piyush? sorry I didnt get notified with your comment